# Xam.Plugins.Settings variables does not forget value even after reinstalling the app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have some `Xam.Plugins.Settings` variables in my class that gets checked once my android project launches . My problem is that the project doesn't forget what values I assigned for these variables even after reinstalling the app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xam.Plugins.Settings` use `Shared Preferences` to achieve it in Android, Uninstalling the application will cause all Preferences to be removed. Here is only way to achieve [persistence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?WT.mc_id=blog-montemagnoblog-jamont&tabs=android#persistence) by setting apps that target and run on Android 6.0 (API level 23) and later that use [Auto Backup.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup)

If you enable the Auto backup(This feature is on by default and preserves app data including Shared Preferences), Android preserves app data by uploading it to the user's Google Drive(You need to add Google account in Settings of this android device).

The amount of data is limited to 25MB per user of your app and there's no charge for storing backup data.

Comment: Thanks I changed the value of  ```android:allowBackup="false"``` in ```AndroidManifest.xml```